# Complexity does not match actual growth in running time? (python)

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I ran 2 codes in python then measured the time it took to complete.The codes are quite simple , just recursive maximums. Here it is:
1.

```
def max22(L, left, right):
  if(left>=right):
    return L[int(left)]
  k = max22(L,left,(left+right-1)//2)
  p = max22(L, (right+left+1)//2,right)
  return max(k,p)


def max_list22(L):
  return max22(L,0,len(L)-1)
```

---

```
def max2(L):
  if len(L)==1:
    return L[0]
  l = max2(L[:len(L)//2])
  r = max2(L[len(L)//2:])
  return max(l,r)
```

---

The first one should run (imo) in O(logn), and the second one in O(n*logn).
However, I measured the running time for n=1000 , n=2000 and n=4000,
And somehow the growth for both of the algorithms seems to be linear! How is this possible? Did I get the complexity wrong, or is it okay?
Thanks.

Comment: the first algo couldn't be possibly O(log n) because it checks value of each element

Comment: Why do you think the second algorithm is O(n logn)?

Comment: Hey, as for the second one my instructor told us it was O(n*logn).

Comment: @ScottHunter because each element of list got copied O(log n) times? (But I'm not sure some kind of optimization like reference counting is not used in python, then it may be faster(but it will be O(n log n) still))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because a function is splitting the search space by 2 and then recursively looking at each half does not mean that it has a log(n) factor in the complexity.

In your first solution, you are splitting the search space by 2, but then ultimately inspecting *every* element in each half. Unlike binary search which discards one half of the search space, you are inspecting both halves. This means nothing is discarded from the search and you ultimately end up looking at every element, making your complexity O(n). The same holds true for your second implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The first algorithms is not `O(log n)` because it checks value of each element. It may be shown that it is `O(n)`

As for the second, possibly you just couldn't notice difference between n and nlogn on such small scales.

Comment: Yeah, I had my doubts about this one too. But isn't the right way to compute the complexity of each recursive call, then to multiply it by the height of the tree?

Comment: @Bar the right way to compute these complexities is to express the recurrence relationship for T(n) and apply the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).  Your first one is `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(1)`, which yields an `O(n)` run time (actually, it's Theta rather than O).  The second recurrence is `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)` since slicing will require `O(n)` work, yielding `O(n log n)` run time.

Answer (score 0):

Your first algorithm is  O(n) on a normal machine, so it is not surprising that your testing indicated this.  Your second algorithm is O(n*log in), but it would be O(n) if you were using proper arrays instead of lists.  Since Python builtin list operations are pretty fast, you may not have hit the logarithmic slowdown yet; try it with values more like `n=4000000` and see what you get.

Note that, if you could run both recursive calls in parallel (with O(1) slicing), both algorithms could run in O(log n) time.  Of course, you would need O(n) processors to do this, but if you were designing a chip, instead of writing a program, that kind of scaling would be straightforward...